# Tokenizing data error, while training a dataset with deepspeech

Tags: python, pandas, tensorflow, dataset

I have created a speech dataset to train with DeepSpeech while following this (https://medium.com/@klintcho/creating-an-open-speech-recognition-dataset-for-almost-any-language-c532fb2bc0cf) tutorial.

But, I couldn't trained my dataset with deepspeech.

It gives an error as a result of train command like

```
python DeepSpeech.py --train_files /mnt/c/wsl/teneke_out_bolum1/
```

It throws an error:

> pandas.errors.ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Calling read(nbytes) on source failed. Try engine='python'.

I have created dataset after aeneas force alignment and fine tuning with finetuneas:

Here is my code that I used on Google Colab to train with DeepSpeech:

https://gist.github.com/mustafaxfe/d20be114ca7cea5c47ea5cc85653c761

I found some solutions on Google like

```
data = pd.read_csv('file1.csv', error_bad_lines=False)
```

Also as error output, I may solve with setting

> engine='python'

But, I couldn't figure out where I should change.

So, where should I edit to fix this issue.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your command needs revisiting:

- You're pointing to a train data folder. You should be pointing to a .csv file
- Use Python3

Your run command should look like this. Check the documentation and amend to your needs.

```
   python3 -u DeepSpeech.py \
    --train_files /data/phonetic_speech_dta/train/train.csv \
    --dev_files /data/phonetic_speech_dta/dev/dev.csv \
    --test_files /data/phonetic_speech_dta/test/test.csv \
    --train_batch_size 64 \
    --dev_batch_size 32 \
    --test_batch_size 64 \
    --n_hidden 800\
    --validation_step 1\
    --display_step 1 \
    --epoch 100 \
    --log_level 1 \
    --dropout_rate 0.2 \
    --learning_rate 0.001 \
    --drop_count_weight 3.5 \
    --export_dir /speech2text/norwegian_model/results/model_export/ \
    --checkpoint_dir /speech2text/norwegian_model/results/checkpoint/ \
    --decoder_library_path /home/nvidia/tensorflow/bazel-bin/native_client/libctc_decoder_with_kenlm.so \
    --alphabet_config_path /speech2text/norwegian_model/alphabet.txt \
    --lm_binary_path /speech2text/norwegian_model/lm.binary \
    --lm_trie_path /speech2text/norwegian_model/trie
```